# How to install VSTO Outlook Addin?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am getting this error message when I try to install Outlook Addin from my local system.

> System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this
>   application will not work because the certificate used to sign the
>   deployment manifest for OutlookCrmAddIn or its location is not
>   trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal(ClickOnceTrustPromptKeyValue
>   promptKeyValue, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation,
>   String productName, TrustStatus status)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustUsingPromptKey(Uri
>   manifest, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String
>   productName, TrustStatus status)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.ProcessSHA2Manifest(ActivationContext
>   context, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation,
>   PermissionSet permissionsRequested, Uri manifest,
>   ManifestSignatureInformationCollection signatures,
>   AddInInstallationStatus installState, TrustStatus sha256TrustStatus,
>   X509Certificate2 sha256PublisherCert)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext
>   context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

How to solve this installation issue?

[image: Exception Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means what it says - your VSTO addin must be signed with a certificate that is trusted by the system where the VSTO addin is installed.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, what certificate do I need to use? Shall I use the Visual Studio Test Certificate?

Comment: That is up to you - you can either use a certificate you purchased from a provider (GoDaddy, DigiCert, etc.) that is trusted by the target machine or you can import your own certificate on the target machine. The former is of course more preferable than the latter.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, is it possible to save outlook mail attachment to my local path if the attachment is the type of olOLE?

Comment: It is mentioned here http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_Attachment.htm.
SaveAsFile() is only valid for the olByValue and olEmbeddeditem attachments.Is it possible to save if the attachment is in the types of olOLE and olByReference?